# auto.arima warning unable to fit final model using Maximum Likelihood

Tags: r, warnings

I am trying to understand the warning below. 
 Other than a couple of NaN's in one of my models, I receive estimates of all of my coefficients and var.coef's.

Should I use a different option than MLE? What should I do differently or what does it imply?

```
Warning messages:
1: In auto.arima(TARHour[, 6], stepwise = TRUE, xreg = TARHour[, 7:24]) :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
2: In sqrt(diag(TARHour.mod$var.coef)) : NaNs produced
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26999/auto-arima-warns-nans-produced-on-std-error) for the possible solution